# data from JSON to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, geolocation, mapbox

i have
...

```
    myLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            lon: console.log(e.latlng.lng),

            lt: console.log(e.latlng.lat),
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        }
```

...
how can i pass lon and lt to rails controller

this is on localhost

Answer (score 2):

You can read the json from the rails controller as params[:geometry]
Just make sure you have a post route sending the json to that controller action.